# Multiple monitors on linux

Tags: linux, centos, xorg

I am using a special configuration of monitors on some computers with two monitors. On old setup with NVidia graphics card I used `xorg.conf` with two screens setup. I was able to start different windows managers on each monitor, because one was DISPLAY :0.0 and another was DISPLAY :0.1.

Now I try to migrate from CentOS5 to CentOS7 and also computers have onboard Intel graphics instead of NVidia.

Whatever I try I only get DISPLAY :0.0. `xdpyinfo` says that the number of screens is 1 and dimensions of that screen are combined dimensions of both monitors.

There is no more xorg.conf in CentOS7. I would rather use `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory where I could put parts of xorg.conf, which are special.

How could I start xorg in that way that each separate screens and not one combined display? I want screens `:0.0` and `:0.1`.

I used some xrandr commands to rotate one of the screen, etc. Can I add as display with xrandr?

Comment: I usually just use something like `xrandr  --output DP2 --mode 1920x1200 --above eDP1`, where eDP1 is my laptop's screen and DP2 is the external monitor.

Comment: I have no problems displaying graphics on both screens. I want them to be separate screens (:0.0, :0.1) to be able to run different windows managers on them and that windows could not be moved from one screen to another. I have tried xrandr commands as you suggested and they do not provide what I need.

Comment: Oh, I see. Unfortunately, I've never tried that with xrandr :-(

Comment: I used ZaphodHeads option a while ago and I don't know whether this still works. I will try it.

Comment: I suspect the screens are being combined by a feature called "xinerama".  I suggest checking for that.  And if it is on, turn it off.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution here https://askubuntu.com/a/419614/217214. There is one thing to be careful of. xrandr reports `HDMI-1`, `HDMI-2` and `eDP-1` outputs on my graphics adapter. However, I had to use `HDMI1`, `HDMI2` and `eDP1` in xorg.conf file.

I did not use `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file. I added a file `20-screens.conf` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory. The file is very similar to the one provided in the solution https://askubuntu.com/a/419614/217214. So I don't see the point of repeating it here.